# shell script- sed pattern to insert double quotes in string values & save to array as values

Tags: shell

i'm storing some string values in a string variable

metaItems="$(git diff HEAD~1 --name-only)"

echo "${metaItems}"

for e.g.
OUTPUT:

metaItems= 
(src/profiles/API Only.profile src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile)

i want to create an array with these values in double quotes from metaItems variable like

array=("src/profiles/API Only.profile" "src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile")

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've finally given enough information for us to tell what you're really doing... you're going about it all wrong. It's a lot simpler and easier and less error prone to just create your array from the `git diff` output directly, instead of trying to store it in another intermediate variable:

```
mapfile -t array <<< $(git diff --name-only HEAD~1)
```

will (Assuming none of the filenames printed out by `git diff` have newlines in them) save its output in `array`, one line/filename per element.

Comment: Shawn.. it's not working as expected

mapfile -t array <<< $(git diff --name-only HEAD~1)
echo ${array[@]}

OUTPUT:

+ mapfile -t array
++ git diff --name-only HEAD~1

+ echo src/profiles/API Only.profile src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile
src/profiles/API Only.profile src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile

NO DOUBLE QUOTES ENCLOSED WITH VALUES.

Comment: @PravindraSinghKhatri `echo ${array[@]}` will be highly misleading about what the array actually contains. Try `declare -p array` instead.